# Check if a key with a certain prefix exists in Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

How would I check if there's a key that starts with a particular prefix, similar to "folders"?

Comment: Also see [Check if folder exist in s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38285326/5989200)

Answer (score 6):

[The docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) say it is possible to specify a `prefix` parameter when asking for a list of keys in a bucket. You can set the `max-keys` parameter to 1 for speed. If the list is non-empty, you know the prefix exists.

Tools like [boto's bucket.list() function](http://readthedocs.org/docs/boto/en/2.0/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.list) expose prefixing and paging as well.

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over all S3 files in your bucket that start with 'some/prefix/' in ruby, do the following using the aws-sdk gem:

```
AWS.config :access_key_id => "foo", :secret_access_key => "bar"
s3 = AWS::S3.new
s3.buckets['com.mydomain.mybucket'].objects.with_prefix('some/prefix/').each do |object|
    # Do something with object (an S3 object)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Required: `aws-java-sdk` jar

```
credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
config = new ClientConfiguration();
client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config );
client.doesBucketExist(bucketName+"/prefix");
```