# Check if folder exist in s3 bucket

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

How can I check if some folder exists in my s3 bucket using Ruby on Rails?

I’m using AWS:S3 official gem
After initializing the global connection

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id => 'my_key_id', :secret_access_key => ‘my_secret’)
```

I have bucket named: `myfirstbucket`

With folder inside named: `my_folder`

With file inside my_folder named: `my_pic.jpg`

When I try to check if `my_pic.jpg` exist it work just fine

```
s3object.exists? “/my_folder/my_pic.jpg” , “myfirstbucket”
=>  True
```

How can I check only if the folder exists?

```
s3object = AWS::S3::S3Object
s3object.exists? “/my_folder/” , “myfirstbucket”
=>  False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a key with a certain prefix exists in Amazon S3 bucket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551347/check-if-a-key-with-a-certain-prefix-exists-in-amazon-s3-bucket)

Answer (score 6):

Use `Bucket#objects`:

```
bucket.objects({prefix: 'my/folder/'}).limit(1).any?
```

> Returns a `Collection` of `ObjectSummary` resources. No API requests are
>   made until you call an enumerable method on the collection.
>   `Client#list_objects` will be called multiple times until every
>   `ObjectSummary` has been yielded.
>
> *—http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Bucket.html#objects-instance_method*

Comment: This seems like the only possible way to test for this condition because folder "foo/" never technically "exists" in S3.  The "existence" of a folder is effectively defined by the existence of objects whose key prefix matches "foo/".

Comment: Yep. Or there's sparse or hard to find documentation about how to access via API the placeholder "dir" that a user can create and which persists via AWS S3 console. Here's an interesting article that is definitely talking about v1: http://deadprogrammersociety.blogspot.com/2008/01/making-s3-folders-in-ruby.html

Comment: Also we can call `S3::Client#list_objects_v2` directly as `resp = client.list_objects_v2(bucket: 'yourBucket', prefix: 'your/folder/', max_keys: 1)` and `resp.contents.any?`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to check

1. object key with trailing slash "/" is exists
2. If not exists, Is there any item in the directory?

For example:
You have file "my_file" under folder "my_folder".
The AWS S3 record `my_folder/my_file` will exist offcourse, but `my_folder/` may not exists.

So you have to check twice

```
if bucket.object("my_folder/").exists?
  true
else
  bucket.objects({prefix: "my_folder/"}).limit(1).any?
end
```

See the document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html

Answer (score 1):

You could make a tree from you bucket.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/Tree.html

```
tree = bucket.as_tree
tree.children.select(&:branch?).collect(&:prefix).include?(“/my_folder/”)
```

Comment: what is the way in php for same activity?