# Check if folder exist on Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I have created a folder on Amazon S3 bucket named as 'test'
using following code

```
            var bucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bucketName"].ToString();
            var AccessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessKey"].ToString();
            var SecretAccessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretAccessKey"].ToString();
            IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(AccessKey, SecretAccessKey, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);


            //Create folder with company name

            var folderKey = "test"+ "/"; 
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
            request.BucketName = bucketName;
            request.StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard;
            request.ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.None;
            request.Key = folderKey;
            request.ContentBody = string.Empty;
            PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request);
```

Now I want to check whether it is exist there or not..

Found some solution here on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285326/check-if-folder-exist-in-s3-bucket) which is in ruby, but i need solution in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use AWSSDK.S3 NuGet package. This way you can create a AmazonS3Client and Get a list of buckets by calling `var bucketsResponse = await client.ListBucketsAsync()` then you can do `if (bucketsResponse.Buckets.Any(x => x.BucketName == "test"))` to check if your 'test' bucket exists.

Comment: what is bucketsResponse?

Comment: The response of the client.ListBucketsAsync call. I'll edit my answer